# Problems in telegram bot commands

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I'm creating a bot that sends math problems in image format. I wanted to create two two functions for different commands, so that one command only sends one genre of question, while the other sends another genre. Example: /random sends general problems, while /comb sends combinatorial problems.

My attempt:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['random', 'comb'])
async def random_cat(message: types.Message):
    captions = ["Nice problem!", "Niceeeeee :eyes:",
                "Noice", "Very cool"]
    caption = random.choice(captions)
    asyncio.create_task(fetch_cat())
    if dp.message_handler(commands=['random']):
        for image in [random.choice(["quest1.jpg", "quest2.jpg", "quest4.jpg", "quest5.jpg", "quest6.jpg",
                                    "quest7.jpg", "quest8.jpg","quest9.jpg", "quest10.jpg", "quest11.jpg", "quest12.jpg"])]:
            f = open(image, 'rb')
            photo = f.read()
            f.close()        
    elif dp.message_handler(commands=['comb']):
        for item in [random.choice(["quest14.jpg", "quest15.jpg"])]:
            r = open(item, 'rb')
            photo = r.read()
            r.close()             
    # _id = random.random()
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                         photo=photo,
                         caption=emojize(
                             caption) if caption == captions[1] else caption,
                         reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Even with the code, the bot sends the same messages for the same command. How to solve this? If possible, how can I change the codes to be able to put new commands for other types of questions in the future?

Comment: create two separated functions `@dp.message_handler(commands=['random'])` and `@dp.message_handler(commands=['comb'])` - and it will be simpler to find problem

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct `if dp.message_handler(commands=['random']):` - because `message_handler()` is not for checking command. I think it should be `if message == 'random':` but if this doesn't work then better run every command in separated function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dp.message_handler(commands=['random'])` is NOT for checking command but for assigning function to command.

I tested and it has to be

```
if message.text == '/random':
    # ... code ...

elif  message.text == '/comb':
    # ... code ...
```

and if you want to run commands with parameters then use `str.startswith()`

```
if message.text.startswith('/random'):
    # ... code ...

elif message.text.startswith('/comb'):
    # ... code ...
```

Or you can split message to get command and arguments as list.

```
    cmd, *args = message.text.split(" ")
    
    if cmd == '/random':
       # ... code ...

    elif cmd == '/comb':
        # ... code ...
```

If there is no arguments then `args` will be empty list.

---

Full working code:

Because some code is the same for `/random` and `/comb` so I moved it to separated function `send_question()`

And I keep images in global variables - they don't have to be created again and again when command is executed.

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import os
import random
import asyncio

API_TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
print(API_TOKEN)

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# ------------------------------------------

def emojize(x):
    return x

async def send_question(message, all_photos):
    
    captions = ["Nice problem!", "Niceeeeee :eyes:", "Noice", "Very cool"]
    caption = random.choice(captions)
    print('caption:', caption)

    image = random.choice(all_photos)
    print('image:', image)

    with open(image, 'rb') as f:
        photo = f.read()

    asyncio.create_task(fetch_cat())

    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                         photo=photo,
                         caption=emojize(caption) if caption == captions[1] else caption,
                         reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)

# ------------------------------------------

random_photos = ["quest1.jpg", "quest2.jpg", "quest3.jpg", "quest4.jpg",
                 "quest5.jpg", "quest6.jpg", "quest7.jpg", "quest8.jpg",
                 "quest9.jpg", "quest10.jpg", "quest11.jpg", "quest12.jpg"]            

comb_photos = ["quest14.jpg", "quest15.jpg"]
    
@dp.message_handler(commands=['random', 'comb'])
async def random_cat(message: types.Message):

    print(message.text)
    #print(dp.message_handler(commands=['random']))
    
    cmd, *args = message.text.split(" ")
    print(cmd, args)
    
    if cmd.startswith('/random'):
        await send_question(message, random_photos)
    elif cmd.startswith('/comb'):
        await send_question(message, comb_photos)

# ------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also run it as two separated functions

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['random'])
async def random_cat(message: types.Message):
    
    await send_question(message, random_photos)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['comb'])
async def random_cat(message: types.Message):

    await send_question(message, comb_photos)
```

Comment: Also, you can accept a `command` into the handler like this: `async def random_cat(message: types.Message, command: Command.CommandObj): ...`, and use `command.command` and `command.args` for command and its arguments respectively. `Command` for type hint can be imported from `aiogram.dispatcher.filters`.